# How can I make Eclipse find the javafx.base module?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Please be nice. I am a noob. I have more experience with Visual basic dot net, having completed a course in it. I'm about to start a Java course. I noticed code in my book for GUI programming. I downloaded javafx and I thought I'd have an example program running in just a few minutes and now it's been a few days and I still can't get it to work and looking for help is like finding a needle in a haystack. Different videos often have the same content. I am just lost and hope someone can help me.

Anyways, it keeps saying `Module javafx.base not found` whenever I run the program.

Here’s what I have set up. I’m trying to be as verbose as possible, because I can’t see how it is unable to detect the module when I’ve basically placed it everywhere.

For starters I made the application **FirstJavaFXProject** using **New...** and then **Other...** and **JavaFX Project Wizard**. I unchecked the **Create module-info.java** checkbox. I left it set at **Create separate folders** for sources and class files under **Project Layout**.

Under **Run Configurations**,
Under **Java Application** I have a **configuration** called **FX_Test**.
I have **Include system libraries** when searching for a main class checked under the main tab.
I have `--module-path "redacted" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`
I have the redacted path name starting with `C:\` and ending with a `lib\`

I unchecked Use the `-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInException Messages argument when launching` checkbox. Somewhere where I was looking for advice it suggested to do that. I don’t remember exactly where though.

Under **dependencies** and under **ModulePathEntires** is the **JavaFX SDK library** as well as each individual **.jar** file from within the library.
Under **dependencies** and under **Classpath Entries** is the **FirstJavaFXProject**, **JRE System Library [JavaSE-17]**, and each **.jar** file from within the **JavaFX SDK library**.
Each of the **.jar** files I need are in the **Source Lookup Path** under the **Source** tab.

In **Properties** for **FirstJavaFXProject** I have the **JavaFX SDK** and the **JRE System Library [JavaSe-17]** under **ModulePath** along with every **.jar** file from the **JavaFX SDK library** individually.
I have the same in the **Classpath**.

I also have each `.jar` added under the **JRE system libraries** under Installed **JREs** under **Java** under **Preferences** under **Window**.

I think I’ve been thorough about describing this but I honestly tried so many things that I’m not sure.

It’s bewildering. I know exactly where the **javafx.base** module is. I have the **.jar** file containing the module referenced in a number of locations which should cause the program to see the module. Yet it still does not see the module.

Is there any way to directly select a module and tell Eclipse to find it regardless of your other settings? I know that’s probably not the most efficient solution but I’m willing to resort to it if all else fails.

I read somewhere this could have something to do with **ant** but it was confusing what I was supposed to try in relation to that.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow Official Documentation**

Documentation on using JavaFX and Eclipse is at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse).

I advise following the instructions which include using a build tool, for example, the section titled "JavaFX and Eclipse: Non-modular with Maven".  If followed exactly, it should work without a problem.

Using the official documentation is the best place to start rather than videos on the net. Especially any getting started guides previously produced that targeted Java versions < 11 should be completely disregarded.

**Consider an alternate IDE if you are having difficulties with your current one**

If you are completely new to Java and aren't tied to a given IDE, perhaps just download IntelliJ Idea community edition and use the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).  That is definitely preferable to spending days trying to get something to run.

**FAQ**

> I read somewhere this could have something to do with ant but it was confusing what I was supposed to try in relation to that.

Don't use ant, it is antiquated, use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle, of the two I would advise Maven when first starting.  Disregard any tutorial that advises using ant.

> Is there any way to directly select a module and tell Eclipse to find it regardless of your other settings?

I don't know Eclipse, but the standard way to do this is to use a build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle).

Modern IDEs, and I am sure that would include Eclipse, all have in-built functionality to synchronize project dependencies specified for the build tool with the IDE, so you don't need to configure the dependencies manually with the IDE.

Using a build tool combined with IDE integration is the preferred way of handling dependencies and has *many* advantages over trying to download and configure them manually within an IDE.